# Не загружаются PNG изображения на сайт Opencart

Tags: opencart

Сайт на OpenCart 2.3.0.2.3. Импортирую товары на сайт через модуль Import/Export. Все импортируется хорошо, но не загружаются изображения товаров с расширением .png (фото .jpg нормально загружаются). Пути прописаны правильно. Имена изображений на английском языке, без символов. Подскажите пожалуйста возможные решения.

Comment: Ну вы смело можете написать автору модуля. А если используете нулл, то shame on u

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, попробую.